# Браузер при работе с функцие поиска sarche.php выдает ошибку.

Tags: php

Подскажите пожалуйста!Создал поисковик на странице, при нажатие enter или поиск в поисковой строке браузер выводит всю нужную информацию и выводит ее правильно, но почему-то с вверху выводит ошибку

Notice: Undefined index: sort in /var/www/r0058300/data/www/arty21.ru/PHP/search.php on line 305

ссылается на эту часть php-кода: $sort = $_GET['sort'];

хотя все вроде хорошо и то что нашел он правильно вывел на экран?
Браузер ругается на сортировку, хотя все вывел правильно.

Вот часть PHP кода:

```
//Извлечение идентификатора типа сортировки поисковой строки из URL c помощью суперглобального массива $_GET

$sort = $_GET['sort'];//на эту переменную ругается браузер.
$user_search = $_GET['usersearch'];

// Расчет данных, деобходимых для разбиения текста результатов поиска на странице 
$cur_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

$results_per_page = 5;//количество объявлений на странице

$skip = (($cur_page - 1) * $results_per_page);

 //создание таблицы с результатами поиска  
echo '<table border="0" cellpadding="2">';

//Вывод заголовков таблицы результатов поиска
echo '<tr class="heading">';

echo generate_sort_links($user_search, $sort);
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: > Notice: Undefined index: sort in /var/www/r0058300/data/www/arty21.ru/PHP/search.php on line 305

=

> Внимание: несуществующий индекс: sort на строке 305

В `$_GET` просто нет этого индекса, вы обращаетесь к пустоте, что весьма логично выдает предупреждение о том, что в переменную ничего не поало (по умолчанию php ожидает присвоение чего-то реального). Решается это просто - через условие:

    $sort = isset($_GET['sort']) ? $_GET['sort'] : null; // вместо null - нужное значение по умолчанию, которое будет выставляться, когда индекс sort буедт остутствовать в $_GET

Comment: Спасибо тебя большое! Я понял:) А, то второй день бился над этой проблемой!

Comment: > А, то второй день бился над этой проблемой!

омг